# if range in column <> x value condition in google sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, is-empty

I'm totaling drawing a blank here on how to do this...

```
             A    
       #1
       #2
       #3
       #4   foo
       #5  
       #6   bar
```

if any cells A1 through A5 does not equal "foo" then return "" for A6. I will iterate this through all rows to check the rows above.

So in the above example it would return "bar" for A6. If A4 was empty it should return "" for A6

=IF(COUNTA(A1:A5)<>"foo",""

Update: I have managed a workaround using an adjacent column where I put:

```
=index($A$1:A5="foo",COUNTA($A$1:A5))
```

Then I can just toggle the true/false output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`COUNTA`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093991?hl=en) function.

```cpp
=IF(COUNTA(A1:A5)=0,,<value_if_false>)
```

By the way, it's bad practice to return an empty string `""`, if you want to return no value just leave the argument empty.

```cpp
IF(condition,"",value_if_false)   Bad practice   
IF(condition,,value_if_false)     Good practice  ✔
```

Comment: IF(COUNTA(a1:a5<>"foo","")

Comment: sorry I actually need to add a value for the condition instead of an integer.

Comment: your question was: `if cells A1 through A5 are empty then return "" for cell A6`, my answer addressed that specific question. Now you are asking a different question so it's best you create a new post.

Comment: I just updated the question to avoid posting another question.

Comment: Your answer led me to my answer. thanks